# Unable to add pages to menu

Tags: php, wordpress

1. I have created few pages and posts in my site.
2. I am able to add posts to the menu.
3. I am unable to add pages to the menu.

Note: screenshot attached as image.
(The wheel is rotating but adding to the menu)

Workarounds: Deactivated plugins, Latest wordpress version.

Please suggest me solution or let me in which file i have to update side menu information of wordpress files.[image]

Comment: you are able to add single page at a time in menu, not by selecting all.

Comment: check for any error in console in browser @prvreddy

Comment: @dineshkashera, I tried with single page also. But, same result.

Comment: @charankumar, No errors